# Convexity of $ (a+b)^{1/n}$

Tags: convexity-inequality

How to prove that $(a+b)^{1/n} \le a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}$ by the convexity of $(a+b)^{1/n}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To receive attention, you need to show effort (what you have tried, looked up, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE: as a hint take $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x+1}$ and prove for concavinty of $f(x)$ then use $$\sqrt[n]{x+1}\leq \sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{1}$$  now it suffice to put $x=\frac ab$ and multiply both sides by $\sqrt[n]{b}$

extra hint: if you accept  $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x+1}$ is concave function,so
$$\sqrt[n]{x+1}\leq \sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{1}\\
\text{ put } x=\frac ab \to 
\\\sqrt[n]{\frac ab+1}\leq \sqrt[n]{\frac ab}+\sqrt[n]{1}\\\text{ multiply by} \sqrt[n]{b} \text{both sides} $$

Comment: sorry but I tried now to prove that f is convex and that $\sqrt[n]{x+1}\leq \sqrt[n]{x}+\sqrt[n]{1}$  but with no conclusion ... extra hint pls

Comment: @user854662 How did you try to prove $f$ is convex? What tools/definitions do you use?

Comment: oh sorry, this is a concave function. I write without care . I'll correct it .  but the solution is true  for a concave function

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function   read this about concave function

Comment: as a simple example of concave function see $$\sqrt{a+b}\leq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$$